# flutter how do pagination in screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new at flutter and I have been searching for proper result of pagination for 2 days..I get more than 1000 items from API . I would like  to dispaly only 20 items (card) to user.then if the user scroll down , the screen will display the next 20 items .

My code :

```
 class Status extends StatefulWidget {
      Status({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      String title;
      @override
      _StatusState createState() => _StatusState();
    }

    class _StatusState extends State<Status> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
    
      ObdApi obdApi = ObdApi();
      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
               body: Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder<ActiveObd>(
                      future: obdApi.getActiveObd(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.none:
                            return Text('no connection');
                          case ConnectionState.active:
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                            break;
                          case ConnectionState.done:
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Center(
                                child:
                                new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            } else {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                var activeobd = snapshot.data;
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount:snapshot.data.obds.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context , index){
                                    final obd = activeobd.obds[index];
                                    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(obd.dateOBDCommand);
                                    String result = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s').format(date);
                                    return Card(
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Container(
                                              height: 30,
                                                child: Text("${obd.description}")),
                                            subtitle: Text(result.toString()),
                                            trailing: Text("${obd.value}"),
                              } else {
                                return Text('No Data');
                              }
                            }
                            break;
                          default:
                            return Container();
                            break;
}
```

How i can do that ?
thanks in advance

Comment: What is your purpose for using pagination if you're already fetching all the items at once?

Comment: my screen fetching 1000 items at once .It's not good for me . I want to fetch 20 by 20 on screen @happy_san

Comment: You are using `ListView` it loads the items lazily and not all the items would be rendered. But if you want to fetch 20 items at a time and show them then you'd need to update your api and enable pagination and use the package @lee3 has suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) package. There is a link to the tutorial on the page as well.